# How to show if the assertions are true?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, education

1. Let $X$ be a random variable. If $X^3$ admits an expected value, then $X$ admits an expected value.
2. Let $X$ be a real random variable. If $e^X$ admits an expected value, then $X$ admits an expected value.

Comment: What have you tried thus far to solve the problem?

Comment: What does "X admit an expected value" mean?

Comment: @MattiP. Presumably that $X$ has a finite expected value (according to Lebesgue integration)